# How to save dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() 's output (dlib.rectangles) in a Python Script (Flask Server)?

Tags: python, flask, dlib

I’m building a Web App using Flask.

**On the Client-side (JavaScript)**, I have a Script that, using the Client’s Webcam, “grabs” a frame and sends it to the Server. **On the Server-side (Flask)**, I have a Python Script that uses DLib to detect a face in that frame.

The App runs but, since I use the **dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()** (to detect the face) in every single frame, this increases the response time of the Server (the response takes a total of 125 ms of which 83% are used by the  dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()).

I’m trying to implement the solution presented by Davis King (the author of DLib) in the GitHub Issue #1556: “run the detector only every few frames”.
However, I’m not being able to save the dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()’s output into a Session object.

Here is the error that I get:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'rectangle' is not JSON serializable
```

I think that the problem has something to do with the fact that the output of the dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() has type: class 'dlib.rectangles'. However, I’m not being able to figure out the solution.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the solution*:** dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()'s output has to be converted into a JSON compatible object, in order to be stored in a Session. Later on (i.e. to be used in the following requests), it has to be converted again into its original type.

(*Credit to Miguel Grinberg)